# Apache Superset connection to Apache Drill with Sql Alchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, apache-superset, apache-drill

I am trying to setup Superset in my local. I have a windows system, so i used VM Virtual Box, with Ubuntu 22.04 to setup and run the superset. I followed the docker instructions. Used the `docker compose up` command in order to start.

The I installed the SQL Alchemy following the https://thedataist.com/visualize-anything-with-superset-and-drill tutorial.

I have an Apache Drill hosted on a server online.

When i try to add the database using the url ***drill+sadrill://external-ip:8047?use_ssl=False*** , i am getting the following error.
`sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:drill.sadrill`

I have tried various solutons, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the sadrill package https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-drill/ ?

Comment: Yes, followed the instructions for all that

Comment: Probably the package is installed in a different (virtual) environment from sqlalchemy. If you are following the instructions from the link, ensure that the `python` that calls `setup.py install` is the same `python` that you used to install `sqlalchemy`.

Comment: I have used same python i expect, is there any way to confirm this @snakecharmerb

Comment: You can do `python -m pip list | grep -i sqlalchemy` assuming you have a bash shell. The output should be all installed packages for that python with sqlalchemy in their name.

Comment: SQLAlchemy             2.0.15

sqlalchemy-drill       1.1.4

SQLAlchemy-Utils       0.41.1

They are installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253916/discussion-between-codeforharman-and-snakecharmerb).

Answer (score 1):

Resolved issue by adding the

> requirements-local.txt

file in the docker folder and specifying the dependencies.